# How to use the "jump to cursor" debugger command when debugging Python in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Python debugger supports the jump command to set the next line to be executed.

Can I use this feature when debugging Python code in VS Code?

Comment: Do you mean "Step Over"? If so then it's supported.

Comment: I mean jumping **back** (or forward) to a given line number. This is supported by the debugger - see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-jump).

Comment: I basically want to be able to modify code and reevaluate it without restarting the program, just like it's done in Visual Studio 2017 with C#.

Comment: The extension does not use pdb but ptvsd; different debugger. As for changing values, you can do that from the debug console.

Comment: In Visual Studio you can change/add/remove instructions, jump back and forth, etc. without restarting the program. That's what I'm asking for in VS Code. Any idea where I can request this feature?

Comment: You need to have VS Code itself add support for such debugging and then we can look at exposing it in the Python extension.

Comment: @el_technic0 While jump to cursor / Set Next Statement is supported by Python and works in VS2019 (not sure of VSC), my understanding is "Edit and Continue" (ability to edit a line live like in C#) isnt, today, supported by Python (or the 'official' CPython spec). That said there are variants to CPython and if you got "Edit and Continue" working in any IDE please let me know. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429798/ironpython-support-for-visual-studio-debugging-like-set-next-statement-and-edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

v1.36 of vscode has added this "jump to cursor" functionality, see [debug: jump to cursor in release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_jump-to-cursor).

> **Jump to cursor**
>
> We have added a new debug command Jump to Cursor, which lets you move
>   program execution to a new location without executing any of the code
>   in between. If Jump to Cursor is supported by a debugger, the new
>   command appears in the editor context menu and Command Palette while
>   debugging. Currently this command is only available from the C#
>   extension, but other debug extensions should follow soon.

Now the Python debugger must add the feature.

And there will be a Command Palette alias `Set Next Statement` added soon, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/fb28cedc37fcdd589f6a7d35ef093f324d649a3c (Introduce "Set Next Statement" as an alias for Jump to Cursor).

Comment: Right to [June 2020 (version 1.47)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47) "Jump to Cursor" changed to "Set Next Statement". But AFAIK, it supports only C# (nor C, nor Python)

Answer (score 1):

This feature has now been added to vs code for python, open the command palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and search for Jump to Cursor.

[image]