# How to use mouse to run to cursor or set next statement in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, usability

In Visual Studio, it's really fast and easy to move the debugger somewhere with the mouse by hovering next to the line and clicking the icon that appears:

[image]

Similarly, you can move the debugger back to a previous statement by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key down while hovering:

[image]

How do I access this behavior in VS Code?  The only options I can see are to right-click and select from the context menu, or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd> to search for the command, [as described in this video](https://youtu.be/v-7lO3zLpPg?t=40).  Both these options are tedious compared to the inline mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an action item for this in the context menu (right click menu) of the editor when you are in a debug session context. "Run to Cursor".

There's also "Jump to Cursor" (see [How to use the "jump to cursor" debugger command when debugging Python in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53362299/11107541)).

Note that you can also bind the command to a keyboard shortcut. The command ID to use in your keybindings.json is `editor.debug.action.runToCursor`.

If you want something just like you've shown in your screenshot- a button in the gutter, you can either look for or write an extension that adds such a button, or [create a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for such a feature. I tried googling to see if a feature-request for such a feature had already been raised by googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues "run to cursor" button`" but didn't find an existing one (all I found was a loosely related one: [Add 'Run to cursor' to VS Code debug floating bar #116250](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116250)).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.